# SQL: Filter products by a list of properties

Tags: mysql, sql, join, filtering, union

I have a table called `products`. (*id, name, price*), a table called `properties` (*id, name, type*) and a table called `product_properties` (*id, property_id, product_id, value*).

Now, I am able to filter products as follows:

1. Start with a list of *product_ids*.
2. For each (property, value) we want to filter on:

   1. product_ids = `SELECT 'product_properties'.'product_id' FROM 'product_properties' WHERE 'product_properties'.'product_id' IN [list,of,product,ids] AND 'product_properties'.'property_id' = property_id AND 'product_properties'.'value' = 'some value here'`
3. Repeat step 2 until we've filtered all wanted properties.
4. Finally, select all matched products using `SELECT * FROM 'products' WHERE 'products'.'id' IN [list,of,product,ids]`

This method needs N+1 database queries for N filters. I am hopeful that it is possible to combine this in one query.

I tried the following, which does not work:

- INNER JOIN/OUTER JOIN -> Discards all product_properties pointing to a product rows except the first, and then tries to enforce all *N* ids and values on it.
- UNION -> This returns a list with products that match *one or more* filters, instead of *all* filters.

How can this be accomplished with a single database query(or as little as possible)?

I am working with Ruby on Rails, which means that I'd like the result to work both in MySQL and SQLite.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would attempt to solve it:

```
WITH FILTERS (property_id, filter_value) AS
(
          SELECT 1, 'foo'
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'bar'
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'baz'
)
SELECT prods.id
  FROM products prods
  JOIN product_properties props
    ON ( props.product_id = prods.id )
  JOIN filters f
    ON ( f.property_id = props.property_id AND f.filter_value = props.value )
 GROUP BY prods.id
HAVING COUNT(1) = ( SELECT COUNT(1) FROM filters )
```

Here is what this is doing:

- First, you provide the list of filters as part of the 'WITH' clause so that it can be in the same query.  I'm hypothetically adding 3 filters on 3 different properties having the values 'foo', 'bar', and 'baz'.
- Second, perform a query that matches the filters to the products.  This is what the `SELECT` through the `JOIN`s are doing.
- Third, perform a `GROUP BY` on the product id, and `COUNT()` the resulting rows.  In the `HAVING` clause, check to see if the product count is the same as the total number of filters.  If it is, then it must have matched all of them.

NOTE:  You can alternately use your `UNION` approach, and then perform the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT()` on the results to see if it works.  Just be sure that you perform a `UNION ALL` on the IDs rather than just a `UNION`.

Comment: OP requested a MySQL and SQLite compatible solution. While in early 2014, SQLite 3.8.3 provides CTE, MySQL does not, so `With()` will not work.

Comment: Wow! The `UNION ALL ... GROUP BY ... HAVING COUNT()` method works perfectly.

A very nice trick. Thank you very much!